# Java Jsoup : Extract all the text

Tags: javascript, java, html, parsing, jsoup

I have the follwing code.
The doc.body.text() statement doesn't output the text within the style and  the script tags. I read the .text() function code , and it looks for all instances of TextNode. What is a TextNode in Jsoup.

And why is the script text not included in the .text() output.

```
String contex = "<html><body><style>style</style><div>div</div><script>script</script><p>paragraph</p>body</body></html>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(contex, "UTF-8");
    String text = doc.body().text();
    System.out.println("Test text : " + text);
```

Output : paragraphbody

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to use `org.jsoup.select.Elements` to parse the tags like `<script>`.

```
String contex = "<html><body><style>style</style><div>div</div><script>scripts</script><p>paragraph</p><p>body</p><script>787878</script></body></html>";
        Document doc =Jsoup.parse(contex, "UTF-8");
         Elements scriptElements = doc.getElementsByTag("script");

         for (Element el :scriptElements ){                
                for (DataNode dn : el.dataNodes()) {
                    System.out.println(dn.getWholeData());
                }
          }
```

***OP:***

```
scripts
787878
```

Comment: What all elements does .text() function cover ? By elements , I mean div, p, h etc ..

Comment: @user8788828 All except `style`, `script` and `CData`.

Answer (score 1):

> And why is the script text not included in the .text() output.

Because `script` and `style` has *data*, not the *text*.

To get data from `script`'s data, use `getElementsByTag`

```
Elements scriptElements = doc.getElementsByTag("script");
```

and access by `getWholeData`

```
for (Element element :scriptElements ){                
    for (DataNode node : element.dataNodes()) {
        System.out.println(node.getWholeData());
    }
    System.out.println("-------------------");            
}
```

As per [source code](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/parser/HtmlTreeBuilder.java), for `style` or `script` tag is treated as *dataNode* instead of *textNode*

> ```
> void insert(Token.Character characterToken) {
>         Node node;
>         // characters in script and style go in as datanodes, not text nodes
>         final String tagName = currentElement().tagName();
>         final String data = characterToken.getData();
>
>         if (characterToken.isCData())
>             node = new CDataNode(data);
>         else if (tagName.equals("script") || tagName.equals("style"))
>             node = new DataNode(data);
>         else
>             node = new TextNode(data);
>         currentElement().appendChild(node); // doesn't use insertNode, because we don't foster these; and will always have a
>    stack.
>     }
> ```